# Using Jquery to open loading.gif

Tags: jquery

What is the easiest way to implement a page load / loading.gif using jquery, just like any other sites.. It needs white out the page and show loading.gif in the middle of it, until the page loads..
I do not want to write it halfway down the page so it doesn't even have a purpose, i would like for this to load first thing on the page..  Is there a way i can do this without writing static divs on that page?  Preferrably a .js file that does it all without any writing div's/etc to the page?

Comment: Sure its possible. What have you tried? 'Just like any other sites' isn't particularly helpful as there are hundred of millions of sites. Maybe be more specific?

Comment: are you dealing with really slow-loading pages or something?

Comment: I have a div that uses window.onload; but only catches about half of the transaction on that page, i want to capture it from the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that when your visitor first loads a page, you get the nothing but a spinny icon until the page is ready ?

What I'd do as put a DIV at the top of the page with your loading GIF, and another place another div around the page content with display:none on it that contains the main body of the page.

```
<body>
  <div class='loadDiv'>
    <img src='spinner.gif' class='spinner_gif' />
  </div>
  <div class='mainContent' style='display:none;'>
    <p> stuff!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then in your DOM load event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loadDiv').hide();
    $('.mainContent').show();
});
```

This would force your loading div to show until the DOM acknowledges that the page is ready.

Comment: Is there a way to load it all in a .js file, without div's?

Comment: I will concede that this approach isn't so good if you have to consider that some visitors may not have Javascript enabled ...

Comment: `document.ready` is not a good option here, rather it should be `onload` when all other images etc have been downloaded.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, if you do this in a .JS file, you'll have to insert a HTML element into the top of the page and then hide the rest of the content, but because it's JS, you can't necessarily be certain when it's being called, so there may not be a DOM element to insert your loading gif DIV to. If you can solve that, Ehtesham's answer would do this.

Comment: @Ehtesham, he's using jQuery, and document.Ready in this fashion is perfect for hiding some content once the dom has finished parsing the document; after all, he only wants the spinner until the page has finished loading; Onload won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possibility.

```
   window.onload = normalize;
   var laoding_img = $('<img src="loading.gif" />');
   $('body').children(':first').css('display', 'none'); //has to be some container that holds all html

   function normalize() {
       loading_img.remove();
       $('body').children(':first').css('display', 'block');
   }
```

in HTML

```
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $('body').append(loading_img);</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: +1 because this is a better solution if you have to consider users that don't have JavaScript.